# Docky running System App Icon Issue

Tags: icons, 17.10, docky

Got some problems with my [Docky](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Docky/) setup under 17.10.
No icons of system apps are displayed. i.g. Console, Nautilus...
If I pin the console and run it no "running" dot is displayed. In Debug mode I get "Warning: DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID not set and no fallback available."

Answer (score 0):

If I run Ubuntu with Xorg display, docky works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem. Thanks to you I found it is connected to using Xorg or wayland display.